# Time Constant of a circuit - capacitors in parallel or series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image]

When I charge the circuit as shown where the switch is at A, the p.d. across C1 is 10V, which is correct.

When I discharge the circuit, however, by changing the switch S from A to B, the total capacitance of the circuit is 200μF as C1 and C2 are in parallel.

This must mean the time constant of the discharging circuit is

$$200 \times 10^{-6} \times 100 \times 10^3 = 20s$$

In the solution, however, the time constant of the discharging circuit is quoted as 5 seconds, where it states C1 and C2 are in series when the switch is at B.

Who is right, the solutions or me?

Comment: I suggest you redraw the circuit with the switch at B.

Comment: yes I did that but it still doesn't deny that c1 and c2 are parallel @probably_someone

Comment: Moving the switch to B disconnects the battery and the left resistor from the circuit. What remains is one resistor and two capacitors, which are now in series.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337737/capacitors-in-parallel-final-potential-difference I posted a similar question on a different thread with a similar circuit, so why are the two circuits different where in this question it is series and in the other thread, it is parallel?

Comment: Because the capacitors are arranged differently - in that case, they're on opposite sides of the switches, whereas here, they're on the same side.

Comment: @probably_someone so if they are on the same side of a switch, they are in series but on opposite sides of a switch, they are parallel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61245/discussion-between-bob-smith-and-probably-someone).

Comment: Not always; again, it depends on the specific circuit arrangement. The way to tell is to redraw the circuit in each switch position, eliminating any open-circuit branches.

Comment: With the switch in B, the capacitors cannot be in parallel because they are only connected to each other at one terminal.  In order for capacitors to be in parallel, they must be connect to each other on both ends. Because they are not connected to anything else at their common junction, they are in series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the total capacitance of the circuit is 200μF as C1 and C2 are in
>   parallel.

They're not in parallel for either switch position.

When the switch is in position A, C2 and the 100k resistor are in series but one end of the resistor is 'dangling' so there is no path for current through the series combination.

When the switch is in position B, C1 is placed in *series* with the C2 + 100k series RC combination.  This should be obvious since *there is only one path for current, all three circuit elements have identical current*.

If the capacitors were parallel connected, C1 and C2 would 'split' the current through the 100k resistor but clearly, *all* of the current through the resistor is through either capacitor and so, the capacitors are series connected.

As you already know, the equivalent capacitance of 2 identical series connected capacitors is 1/2 the individual capacitance and thus

$$C_{eq} = 50\mu\mathrm{F}$$

and the time constant is

$$\tau = 100\mathrm{k\Omega}\cdot 50\mu\mathrm{F} = 5\mathrm{s}$$

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337737/capacitors-in-parallel-final-potential-difference how does the circuit in this post then vary from that circuit?

Comment: @BobSmith, the key difference is that there are resistors in this circuit and so there are *three* circuit elements connected together on the right hand side when the switch is in position B.  In the circuit at the link, when S1 is open and S2 is closed, there are just two circuit elements, the two capacitors, on the right hand side.  This is a 'degenerate' configuration that is both series and parallel at the same time, i.e., the two capacitors have identical voltage across as with a  parallel connection *and* the two capacitors have identical current through as with a series connection.

Comment: By adding the resistor, a third circuit element, the degeneracy is broken and then *either* the capacitors are series connected or parallel connected.  Since, in this circuit, the capacitors have identical current through, they are series connected.

Comment: @BobSmith, it's possible to connect the resistor differently so that all three are parallel connected.

Comment: @BobSmith, assume for clarity that, with the switch in the B position, the current is out of the 'top' plate of C1.  Since there is only one path and that path is to the resistor, *all* of the current out of C1 enters the resistor's left-most terminal and exits the resistor's right-most terminal.  Again, there is only one path and that is to C2 and so *all* of the current out of the resistor enters C2 through the top plate and exits the bottom plate.  Finally, there is only path and that is to C1 and so *all* of the current out of C2 enters C1 through the bottom plate.  Do you see?

Comment: so the current at any part of the circuit is the same - although I thought current in the circuit decreases exponentially?

Comment: @BobSmith, you're not thinking carefully; that the capacitors have identical current doesn't constrain the time dependence of that current in any way at all.  Yes, the current decays exponentially *and* yes, the exponentially decaying current through each capacitor is identical.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri +1 for solving my problem :)